# How to pass an extra parameter with spring security login form?

Tags: java, spring, security

I am new to Spring. I have a login form with j_username and j_password. I just want to pass two more parameters along with this login form.

In my current form the form action is mentioned as `j_acegi_security_check`.

So it will directly going to `DaoAuthenticationProvider.java` which implements AuthenticationProvider,
InitializingBean, ApplicationContextAware.

In this class i have a method
`public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)throws AuthenticationException`  which validate the username and password.

I want to pass `j_captcha` with this.

I go through many forums and it says that add an intermediate filter.

But I don't have such `UsenamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.

Please gimme a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create your own login form in Spring security. Do your search in that way. Also implement your own `UserDetailService` implementation

Comment: I have already a login form and UserDetalisService. in my project UserDetalisService is jar. I can not modify it

Comment: You must clarify a lot of things. Are you using spring security default login form? What type of authentication you are using? Also post your security configuration. Is it using xml or java/annotation?

Comment: Which version of Spring Security are you using? Or you are still at Acegi Security?

Comment: I am using Acegi Security only

Comment: my login page is "login_page.vm" form submission part of my login is given below                                                                                               `<form method="POST" action="j_acegi_security_check" name="frmLogin">
    
<input type='hidden' autocomplete="off" name='_schema' id="_schema"/>
<input type='hidden'  id='j_username' name='j_username'  autocomplete="off"  /> 
<input type='hidden'  id='j_password' name='j_password' autocomplete="off" />
<input type='hidden'  id='j_captcha' name='captchaEntered'  autocomplete="off"  /> 
</form> `

Comment: After success login it is directing to "DaoAuthenticationProvider.java"

Comment: "DaoAuthenticationProvider.java"                                                                            Class starts like this                                                                                     `public class DaoAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider,
  InitializingBean, ApplicationContextAware {`                                     In this class i have a method                                                                        `public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)` to authenticate username & password

Comment: `username = authentication.getPrincipal().toString();`                               `String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();`              is there any way to take my third parameter here?

Comment: I am using the older version spring.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I got the solution. I created a bypass filter and solved the issue. I can pass the extra parameter with login form in spring security.Thank you